# Failed to load images using SFML Library

Tags: c++, sfml, minesweeper

I have just successfully linked the SFML library to my Visual Studio 2019.  I am trying to run a simple C++ game Minesweeper.  It compiles, gives no error message, but gives weird unexpected results in the runtime window.  It says failed to load images. Please help.  This is a pic of the error message, and see code for game below.

[Failed to load images pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukx0W.png)

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
srand(time(0));

RenderWindow app(VideoMode(400, 400), "Minesweeper!");

int w = 32;
int grid[12][12];
int sgrid[12][12]; //for showing

Texture t;
t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.jpg");
Sprite s(t);

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        sgrid[i][j] = 10;
        if (rand() % 5 == 0)  grid[i][j] = 9;
        else grid[i][j] = 0;
    }

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        int n = 0;
        if (grid[i][j] == 9) continue;
        if (grid[i + 1][j] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i][j + 1] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i - 1][j] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i][j - 1] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i + 1][j + 1] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i - 1][j - 1] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i - 1][j + 1] == 9) n++;
        if (grid[i + 1][j - 1] == 9) n++;
        grid[i][j] = n;
    }

while (app.isOpen())
{
    Vector2i pos = Mouse::getPosition(app);
    int x = pos.x / w;
    int y = pos.y / w;

    Event e;
    while (app.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if (e.type == Event::Closed)
            app.close();

        if (e.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed)
            if (e.key.code == Mouse::Left) sgrid[x][y] = grid[x][y];
            else if (e.key.code == Mouse::Right) sgrid[x][y] = 11;
    }

    app.clear(Color::White);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            if (sgrid[x][y] == 9) sgrid[i][j] = grid[i][j];
            s.setTextureRect(IntRect(sgrid[i][j] * w, 0, w, w));
            s.setPosition(i * w, j * w);
            app.draw(s);
        }

    app.display();
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Return value for `t.loadFromFile("images/tiles.jpg");` is a bool, so it's not containing any decent debugging info other than "Nope. Nuh-uh." but it's a great place to stop the program because anything the program does from here on in is questionable..

Comment: Of course what you really want to know is why'd the image fail to load. Is the working directory where you expect it to be? If not, "images/tiles.jpg" won't cut it.